# NuxtJS Vuetify Background Image v-app-bar as a href

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I use NuxtJS 2 with Yarn and work with Vuetify.
For having the Logo of my app in the center of the v-app-bar I used this code:

```
<template>
   <v-app>
     <v-app-bar app>
       <template v-slot:img="{ props }">
         <v-img v-bind="props" :src="logoUrl" class="pa-4" contain></v-img>
       </template>
     <v-app-bar app>
```

Problem is that I can't create a a href / NuxtLink on this v-img Component.

How can I achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Just simply wrap the `v-img` component in a `nuxt-link` component.

```html
<nuxt-link to="/">
    <v-img v-bind="props" :src="logoUrl" class="pa-4" contain></v-img>
</nuxt-link>
```

Comment: Thought this, too. But don't work as a clickable Image (it is rendered as CSS background image by Vuetify).

Comment: @baer999 Does it have to be an image? I use the same snippet as I sent in multiple projects and I'm able to click the image just fine. (Even though it might not be a real `img` element.)

If you want it to be an `img` element, you'll have to use a regular `<img>` tag, as `v-img` only uses CSS background images.